# Install iPhone application to device without paying

Tags: iphone, xcode, deployment

How can I install my own iPhone application to my [iPod Touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Touch) or iPhone without paying? I follow some documentation, but it always fail. Is there a tested method?

I am using iPhone SDK 3.1.3 with [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) v. 3.1.4. The device is using v. 3.1.3.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried following per chance?

Comment: http://www.vinodlive.com/2009/01/16/how-to-deploy-an-iphone-application-without-an-idp-membership/

Comment: there is an error msg when i type ldid command
util/ldid.cpp(567): _assert(0:arch != NULL)
now my app, launches and close

Comment: i just realize this method only work for ver 2.x

Answer (score 1):

You could try asking a friend somewhere who has registered as an iPhone/iOS developer as a company instead of as an individual to add you as a team member and also add your device to the team provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can jailbreak it, and upload your application, re-spring.

Answer (score 0):

1. Jailbreak
2. Create a new folder with name payload
3. Copy the `.app` file to this folder and compress the folder
4. Rename the ZIP file to `yourname.ipa` and click keep ipa